# Add iframe to facebook page

Tags: html, css

Does anyone could provide good link to ACTUAL information about how to add HTML iframe to my facebook page?

Comment: I don't believe facebook want you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Assuming it's a page, and not a standard profile?

You will need to get this app: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196

Then you can enter code into that app for it to display, you will also need to make sure you select that app as your default landing tab, by clicking "edit" - "default landing tab"